# How do you track your current deployments?

Tags: deployment, architecture, environment

Imagine there is an application consisting from bunch of microservices. All of these microservices can be developed/deployed completely independently from each other. Each microservice can be "described" with several attributes - e.g. current API version, release version, commit hash etc. Along with that, there are several environments used in development process - e.g. Testing environment (often called Sandbox), Staging environment, Pre-Release environment and obviously Production environment.

Is there a convenient tool/way/approach to track, basically, what attribute is currently deployed to which environment? For instance, get a quick access to information like "what is the current version of Restful API at Pre-Release environment"? Or more complex one - "what was this version two month ago"? And of course see the "global picture" as well?

Answer (score 1):

Theres no ready to use solution on the market yet according to my knowledge.

Some teams are using git ops https://www.twistlock.com/2018/08/06/gitops-101-gitops-use/ to get ahead of the chaos challenge a lot of different micro services usually ship with.

Another technology in a somewhat different, yet related direction are micro service meshes, istio https://istio.io/ being one of them.

There are also test approaches like contract testing or heavy integration tests, that are more expensive, but also provide more confidence.